# Nasm hello world failed in visual studio 2013

Tags: windows, visual-studio, nasm

The asm file is t.asm

```
 global _asmp
 section .text

_asmp:
    mov eax, 1
    mov edi, 1
    mov esi, msg
    mov edx, msglen
    syscall
    mov eax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall

    section .data
msg: db "hello, world!", 10
msglen: equ $ - msg
```

The main() located in m.c and called _asmp to print "hello work", m.c is as follow:

```
#include "stdio.h"
extern asmp();

int main()
{
    printf("hi asm\n");
    asmp();
    return 0;
};
```

It was compiled successfully, but failed to run. The configurations in visual studio 2013 are showed as follow

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems to be caused by link, I do not know how to solve this problem, could anyone help?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, the `syscalls` are not documented under windows.  Is that code from linux?

Comment: I had deleted the syscall codes, but it still did not work. I mean that it still crashed when steping in asmp().

Comment: If you have deleted the `syscalls`, what do you expect to happen after you execute `xor edi, edi`?  What's the next instruction you expect it to execute?

Comment: Just to try to ensure main() can call asmp() which is written in the asm file successfully.

Comment: I'm trying to make a point here.  Read your code again.  What instruction do you have after xor (absent syscalls)?  Ahh, you don't have ANY instructions after xor.  So, what do you expect will happen?  If this were a high level language, the compiler would know to return to the caller, since that's what happens when you exit a function.  But asm is not a high level language, so nothing is automatically added for you.  Then what will happen after it finishes the xor? You'll start trying to execute whatever happens to be next in memory (whatever that may be). Usually with unsatisfactory results.